# Why are you allowed to re-define a extern variable in c++?

Tags: c++

I have an extern variable declared in `driver.h`:

```
namespace org::lib {
   extern bool myVar;
   void myFunction();
}
```

I also have it defined in `driver.cpp`:

```
#include driver.h
namespace org::lib {
       bool myVar = false;
       void myFunction(){
          if (myVar){
            //....
          }
       }
}
```

Now I have `main.cpp` which redefines myVar:

```
 #include driver.h
  using org;

  int main(int arc, char** argv){
       lib::myVar = true; //redefines it to be true, while it was defined as false in driver.cpp
       lib::myFunction();    
  }
```

Why doesn't compiling main.cpp give me a redefinition error on `myVar` ? Isn't it defined already in driver.cpp, and redefined again in main.cpp ?

Ah never mind, you are re-assigning it in main.cpp.

Comment: You're not redefining it in main, you're just assigning to it. It is a variable after all.

Comment: You have only one declaration, in `driver.cpp`. The `extern` in `driver.h` just says "This is defined somewhere else" so the compiler won't complain. The linker has to figure out where the real declaration of `myVar` is. If you remove `extern`, you should get a multiple definition error.

Comment: Define what you mean by "define".

Comment: Both `#include driver.h` and `using org;` are not valid syntax. Please take care to write examples that do not contain irrelevant additional mistakes that will make it harder to get the actual point across.

Comment: `extern bool myVar;` declaration of `myVar`. `bool myVar = false;` definition of `myVar`. `lib::myVar = true;` assignment of `myVar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't define the variable in `main`, you assign it a new value